# Why did my cooktop trip the breaker when I cleaned it with too much water?

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens, gas, stove

I have a problem with my miele built-in gas cooktop. I was cleaning it with baking soda and stabilized hydrogen peroxide, afterwards, I rinsed it with water. I was using too much water and one of the burners made a pop sound and I can feel mild heat around the burner. And following that,  the electricity in my whole unit was tripped.

I called in an electrician and he switched on the electricity inside the switch board outside my apartment unit and attempted to turn on the stove. Again, a pop and electricity tripped back off. He plugged out the power cord and asked me to call an electrical appliance repair tomorrow.

What happened inside the stove? Have the fuse inside the stove blown? How does it cause the electricity switch to tripped?

Comment: It may be as simple as drying everything out (with the power off) or as expensive as a blown control board sometimes as high as 200$. If a fuse blew it should have opened the circuit and not tripped the breaker. If you can examine the wires look for the cause of the  "pop" the water could have started conducting and dammaged the insulation, now with dammaged insulation it keeps shorting and tripping the breaker as 1 possibility.

Comment: Simple answer: we don't know. We'd need to look inside the cooktop. And we can't. I'm going to suggest that you call an electrical appliance repairer.

Answer (score 4):

The water apparently got inside the stove and caused a short. If there was a fuse inside there that blew, the breaker wouldn't have tripped. The breaker is detecting the excessive current to the appliance and switching off the power before the wiring inside the wall overheats and start a fire.

The best solution, as the electrician indicated, is to have the appliance repaired or replaced. Until then, leave it disconnected since it's a safety hazard. Without opening the appliance and inspecting the connections, it's difficult to say exactly what inside of it has failed.

Answer (score 0):

I spilled water in my cooktop yesterday and it kept tripping the breaker.  I was going to take the unit out and check the fuse/etc, but I decided first to try using a hairdryer to dry in the knobs and it worked like a champ - no repair call needed this time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in Australia so terminology might be different. At the so called fuse box the RDC pretection was tripping. I  turned all the circuits off and one by one turned them on. And the. By turning off appliances worked out which was tripping the safety.

Gas cooktop Electrolux.

Pulled the trivets off. I had been cooking this evening and a wet lid I had stood upright at the back had dropped onto the glass surface. And the rear left hand burner was in a slight pool of moister. So I fired it.  To try to dry it out faster (and not wait U told tomorrow) I have Used the burner (lit manually) and I have a ppo of something on the stove cooking now so hopefully using the burner for half an hour will help to dry it out.

If it doesn't work now I will try again I the morning. And maybe try drying it out with a hair dryer.

Once upon a time about 16 years ago I ckea er the front panel of a microwave with too much "spray and wipe" and it failed. But I let it thoroughly dry out and it came back to life.  A perfect strategy when parts or electrician aren't available..... As long as you're protected by a good safety.

Here there is the RDC. And the fuse.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the answers already provided. If you still have a problem, you can post a qustion.

Comment: If you do post this as a question, please be sure to edit it for clarity. It's possible that some of those terms are either common in Aus, or are typos - if they're common Aus terms, you may want to look up synonyms for the rest of the world, or if they're typos, correct them before posting.